# Rails to_json belongs_to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models: Cabinet and Workplace.

```
class Cabinet < ActiveRecord::Base

  def as_json(options={})
    options.merge!({except: [:created_at, :updated_at]})
    super(options)
  end

end

class Workplace < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cabinet

  def as_json(options = {})
    options.merge!(:except => [:created_at, :updated_at, :cabinet_id], include:  :cabinet)
    super(options)
  end

end
```

When I called Cabinet.first.to_json I get

```
{
    id: 1, 
    cabinet: "100"
}
```

but when I called Workplace.first.to_json id get

```
{
  name: "first workplace",
  Cabinet: {
           id: 1, 
           cabinet: "100",
           created_at: "#created_at",
           updated_at: "#updated_at"
           }
}
```

Why this? Thanks and sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am following you, but do you want to get just attributes from Workplace model, and not Cabinet data when you do Workplace.first.to_json?

I think it is because you include cabinet in as_json method configuration as explained [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html).

You should either remove it or do this:

```
Workplace.first.attributes.to_json
```

Let me know if I am missing something from your question.

Comment: Sorry, i wrong to put the question. I will get Cabinet object without created_at and updated_at fields: ```{
  name: "first workplace",
  Cabinet: {
           id: 1, 
           cabinet: "100"
           }
}```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your model `Cabinet` has `:id, :cabinet, :created_at, :updated_at` attributes and `Workplace` has `:id, :name, :cabinet_id, ....`.

Now, if you try to fire `Cabinet.first.to_json`, ofcourse it will render the following:

```
{
  id: 1, 
  cabinet: "100"
}
```

becuase that is the attributes belongs to `Cabinet` model. Then you also added these line of code `options.merge!({except: [:created_at, :updated_at]})` that's why it only renders `:id and :name` attributes. And if you try to fire `Workplace.first.to_json` then it will render:

```
{
  name: "first workplace",
  Cabinet: {
       id: 1, 
       cabinet: "100",
       created_at: "#created_at",
       updated_at: "#updated_at"
       }
}
```

because, of these `options.merge!(:except => [:created_at, :updated_at, :cabinet_id], include:  :cabinet)`. You include the model `Cabinet` so it will automatically added to your json.

Comment: i wrong to put the question. I override Cabinet.as_json method, but in this call Workplace.first.to_json(include: :cabinet) not called Cabinet.as_json and result json object includes created_at and updated_at fields.